# ng-if is not working even the condition is passed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In My following function we used the

`"ng-if"[ng-if=\"GoalCard.assignment.totalResponsesToGrade>0**\"]` to show/hide the button but its not showing the button even though the condition is passed.

```
angular.module("goalCard/studentWritingTab.tpl.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("goalCard/studentWritingTab.tpl.html",
    "<div class=\"large-12 columns students-table-wrapper student-writing-passage\">\n" +
    "       <div class=\"summary-report-head\">\n" +
    "           {{locale['label.goalCard.title.writing']}}\n" +
    "       </div>\n" +
    "       <div class=\"small-12 columns students-table table-header goal-student-writing-report border-theme reset-foundation\" flexcroll ><div  id=\"goalCardStudentWritingReport\"></div></div>     \n" +
    "       <div class=\"clear\"></div>\n" +
    "       <div class=\"table-header-passage\"><a class=\"button button-one large-text passge-next right\" wga-click=\"label.goalCard.gradePassages\" ng-if=\"GoalCard.assignment.totalResponsesToGrade>0\" ng-click=\"gradePassages()\">{{locale['label.goalCard.button.writing']}}</a></div>\n" +
    "</div> ");
}]);
```

Comment: Try using ng-show to debug. ng-show won't remove elements from DOM but just hide them, so it may be easier to check for errors. After you'll just have to replace ng-show by ng-if

Answer (score 0):

You're sure

```
GoalCard.assignment.totalResponsesToGrade
```

is rightly instanced?

Try to access it so:

```
ng-if="GoalCard['assignment']['totalResponsesToGrade']>0"
```

Your scope would need to look like:

```
$scope.GoalCard = {};
$scope.GoalCard.assignment. = {};
$scope.GoalCard.assignment.totalResponsesToGrade = 0;
```